# How do I look for a string in a long series of text?

Tags: string, loops

I have a long series of text that I want to mine for a specific term. The following only checks individual characters:
    for i in variable:
        if i == "9"
            print i

But if I want to search for "99", it will never find it because it is iterating over the text file (the variable) one character at a time.

Comment: Please post your complete code.

Comment: How do I post formatted code?

Comment: Just click `edit` and copy and paste the code under your question. If it doesn't look good, I can reformat it.

Answer (score 0):

if you encounter the first matching character of your search string, you would continue matching the next character of the search string and so on.

Comment: Is there a way to skip the steps in between and just tell the loop to look for all instances where "99" appears?